# Creating a PHP json feed and successfully linking it to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

I have a project i am working on that requires sending information from database through a php script using json feed to javascript. Here are the scripts:

This is the javascript:

```
<link rel= 'stylesheet' type='text/css' href='fullcalendar/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="fullcalendar/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="fullcalendar/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="fullcalendar/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fullcalendar/lib/jquery-ui.custom.min.js" ></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {

                left: 'prev,next today',

                center: 'title',

                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'

            },
            editable: true,

            events: "public_calendar.php"
    })
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id='calendar'></div>
</body>
</html>



 ?php require_once("includes/initialize.php"); ?>
<?php require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'database.php'); ?>

<?php
    //Find all the events
    $events = Event::find_all();
         foreach($events as $event):

            $id = (int) $event->id;
            $title = "{$event->event_title}";
            $start = "{$event->start_date}" ." ". "{$event->start_time}";
            $end = "{$event->end_date}" ." ". "{$event->end_time}";
            $url = "event_detail.php";

            echo json_encode( array(
                'id'    => $id,
                'title' => "{$title}",
                'start' => "{$start}",
                'end'   => "{$end}",
                'url'   => "{$url}"
            ));         
        endforeach;

?>
```

This is how the php script should look like:

```
[ {"id":111,"title":"Event1","start":"2013-10-10","url":"http:\/\/yahoo.com\/"},
  {"id":222,"title":"Event2","start":"2013-10-20","end":"2013-10-22","url":"http:\/\/yahoo.com\/"}
]
```

This is how it looks like now:

```
{"id":12,"title":"Matriculation","start":"2013-11-5 08:00","end":"2013-11-5 17:00","url":"event_detail.php"}
{"id":13,"title":"Exam","start":"2013-11-30 09:00","end":"2013-11-30 16:00","url":"event_detail.php"}
{"id":2,"title":"Convocation","start":"2013-12-11 08:00","end":"2013-12-11 19:00","url":"event_detail.php"}
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Do not output each array as a json String. Push all Arrays inside a **main** array and json_encode it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to achieve the result you want is to create an array in PHP, then use `json_encode()` to create the output. You're already doing some of this - you just need a little more:

```
<?php
//Find all the events
$events = Event::find_all();
$eventList = array();            // Assemble list of all events here

     foreach($events as $event):

       $eventList[] = array(              // Add our event as the next element in the event list
            'id'    => (int) $event->id,
            'title' => $event->event_title,
            'start' => $event->start_date." ".$event->start_time,
            'end'   => $event->end_date." ".$event->end_time,
            'url'   => "event_detail.php"
        );         
    endforeach;

    echo json_encode($eventList);       // encode and output the whole list.
?>
```

I've also simplified and shortened some of your code to remove the unnecessary double quotes.