# How to pass an array of events to the FullCalendar jQuery plugin

Tags: php, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using the FullCalendar jquery plugin to display a calendar on my page.  I am now trying to figure out how to populate the calendar with my own events.  I have some code which loops through my query results and builds a `$json_array` of all the events.  This seems to be working because when I output the array to the screen I can see my events and they look properly formatted, like this:

```
    [eventData] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [title] => 09:30 AM Hearing-950 Boundary Rd, South Glengarry PC540 H#559588-Council Chambers - 6 Oak St, Lancaster
                [start] => 2014-04-29
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [title] => 09:30 AM Hearing-6-12 Park St, Brockville PC340 H#559597-Council Chambers - 1 King St W., Brockville
                [start] => 2014-04-30
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [title] => 09:30 AM Hearing-1340 Kingston Rd, Pickering PC430 H#558975-Council Chambers, One The Esplanade, Pickering
                [start] => 2014-04-01
            )
     )
```

In addition to building the `$json_array`, my sample code also builds a string called `$eventString` which also looks like it could be used as the event source for the calendar.  Here is the code which builds both the `$json_array` and `$eventString`:

```
<?php 
$qryEvents = $this->db->query(" SELECT date(tbldeadlines.Date) AS D, 
    time_format(tbldeadlines.HearingStartTime, '%H:%i %p') AS S, 
    tbldeadlines.Type AS T, 
    tbldeadlines.`Property#` AS P, 
    tblproperties.`Property Address` AS A, 
    tblmunicipalities.MunicipalityName AS M,
    tblproperties.`Property Owner` AS O, 
    tbldeadlines.HearingNotes AS N, 
    tbldeadlines.HearingNumber AS H, 
    format(tblproperties.PC,0) AS PC, 
    tblpropertycodes.`SIMPLE PC NAME` AS PCN
FROM tbldeadlines INNER JOIN tblproperties ON tbldeadlines.`Property#` = tblproperties.`Property#`
     INNER JOIN tblmunicipalities ON tblproperties.County = tblmunicipalities.MunicipalitiesCounty
     INNER JOIN tblpropertycodes ON tblproperties.PC = tblpropertycodes.PC
WHERE 1 {$whereCond} 
GROUP BY P, D, T, A, N, H, S");

$evntArray =  $qryEvents->result_array();
$eventString = "";
if(!empty($evntArray)){
    $json_array = array();
    $eventString .= "[" ;
    foreach($evntArray as $row){
        $json_array[] = array("title"=>addslashes($row['S'])." ".addslashes($row['T'])."-".addslashes($row['A']).", ".addslashes($row['M'])." PC".addslashes($row['PC'])." H#".addslashes($row['H'])."-".addslashes($row['N']), "start"=> date('Y-m-d',strtotime($row['D'])));
        $eventString .= "{title:'".addslashes($row['N'])."',start:'".date('Y-m-d',strtotime($row['D']))."'},";
    }
    $eventString .= substr($eventString,0,-1);
    $eventString .= "]";
} 

if($_GET['start'] != "" && $_GET['end'] != ""){
    echo json_encode($json_array); 
}       

$data['eventData'] = $json_array; 
$data['calurl'] = 'http://mysite.ca/admin/view';    
$this->load->view('pts_template', $data);    
?>
```

My problem is that I don't know how to get my results into the calendar. How can I initialize the calendar and reference the array that is already on the page?  Which should I be using, the `$json_array` or the `$eventString`?

Thanks for any ideas you might have.

Comment: I think you are looking for http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_array/.

Comment: Also take a look here http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_function/. I would have one of your urls return a json string (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19554240/creating-a-php-json-feed-and-successfully-linking-it-to-javascript). That would be the best way to communicate between php and your jquery.